# Does anyone know what framework Google Analytics is designed with?

Tags: angularjs, gwt, google-analytics

The customer I am working for enjoys the look/feel of the Google Analytics site.  The look & feel, ajax refreshes, live graphs, etc.

Does anyone know what framework Google uses for producing it?  Are they still using GWT, or have they moved onto something else (such as AngularJS)?

I found a link to the [Google Analytics site on https://www.madewithangular.com/#/sites](https://www.madewithangular.com/#/sites/google-analytics).  Does that mean that the whole Analytics site is designed with Angular?